# Table not Found - Hibernate InheritanceType.JOINED exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm, hibernate-mapping

I'm having problem in hibernate mappings. When I run the project, get this error on runtime. Working fine for other class mappings. I don't know where I'm doing wrong.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7wMP.png)

This is Annotated class named "Account"
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfZOM.png)

This is the "Accounts" table.
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qsbW.png)

Comment: post here the full stack trace

Comment: Remove inheritance it's not necessary